# Deleted data in cassandra come back,like ghost

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have a 3 nodes Cassandra cluster(3.7), a keyspace

```
CREATE KEYSPACE demo WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

a table

```
CREATE TABLE tradingdate (key text,tradingdate date,PRIMARY KEY (key, tradingdate));
```

one day when deleting one row like

```
delete from tradingdate 
where key='tradingDay'and tradingdate='2018-12-31'
```

then the deleted row become ghost, when the query

```
select * from tradingdate 
where key='tradingDay'and tradingdate>'2018-12-27' limit 2;

     key        | tradingdate
    ------------+-------------
     tradingDay |  2018-12-28
     tradingDay |  2019-01-02


select * from tradingdate 
where key='tradingDay'and tradingdate<'2019-01-03' 
order by tradingdate desc limit 2;

     key        | tradingdate
    ------------+-------------
     tradingDay |  2019-01-02
     tradingDay |  2018-12-31
```

So when use order by, the deleted row (tradingDay, 2018-12-31) come back.

I guess I only delete a row on one node, but it still exists on another node. So I execute:

```
nodetool repair demo tradingdate
```

on 3 nodes, then the deleted row totally disappears

So I want to know why use order by, I can see the ghost row.

Comment: what version of cassandra?

Comment: What consistency level are you using when reading?

Comment: i execute query in cqlsh,the default consistency is  ONE.i remember i once met this situation，when set consistency two,would lead to same result

Comment: That's probably the reason. Your delete not propagated to other nodes and with consistency ONE you may read stale data. Try using QUORUM to get more consistency.

Comment: but strangely,when not use order by , i can not get the stale data

Comment: Was any node down white deleted the data?

Comment: @Pandey no node down

Comment: You need to run full repair it will ensure data replication if any reason not replicated.

Answer (score 0):

This is some good reading about deletes in Cassandra (and other distributed systems as well):

http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html

As well as:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDeletes.html

You will need to run/schedule a routine repair at least once within `gc_grace_seconds` which defaults to ten days to prevent data from reappearing in your cluster.

Also you should look for dropped messages in case one of your nodes is missing deletes (and other messages):

```
# nodetool tpstats
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
MutationStage                     0         0      787032744         0                 0
ReadStage                         0         0     1627843193         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0     2257452312         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0       99910415         0                 0
CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
HintedHandoff                     0         0           1582         0                 0
MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
CompactionExecutor                0         0        6649458         0                 0
MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0          17987         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0             46         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0       22766295         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0              8         0                 0
MemtablePostFlush                 0         0         127844         0                 0
ValidationExecutor                0         0              0         0                 0
Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
MemtableFlushWriter               0         0          17851         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0           8669         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
Native-Transport-Requests         0         0      631966060         0                19

Message type           Dropped
READ                         0
RANGE_SLICE                  0
_TRACE                       0
MUTATION                     0
COUNTER_MUTATION             0
REQUEST_RESPONSE             0
PAGED_RANGE                  0
READ_REPAIR                  0
```

Dropped messages indicate that there is something wrong.